# How to check liked fan page from iframe apps via Graph API and Javascript-SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Here is my code, this is working fine only on apps developer account. WT is my wrong?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
var APP_ID   = 'XXXXX';
var PAGE_ID  = 'XXXXX';

FB.init({
    appId  : APP_ID,
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
});

FB.api('/me/likes/' + PAGE_ID, function(response) {
    t = $.toJSON(response);
    alert(t);
});
```

}

**RESULT**
developer account:

```
{"data":[{"name":"111222333","category":"Small business","id":"281428705206834","created_time":"2011-09-02T14:14:37+0000"}]}
```

non-developer account:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}}
```

Comment: Is your application in sandbox mode (inside app settings)?

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the page settings. If the page is set to be invisible, as in only visible for the administrators of that page, that could be a cause why you are getting  that error.

Have you set your page available for everyone?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see a user likes with graph api you will need the permissions to do so. user_likes

> See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/